# How to change the auto rounding of floats in a numpy array after the array has been divided by a constant?

Tags: numpy, rounding

Using Python 2.7, and numpy 1.16.5

I want to convert array elements from inch to foot

```
FootToInch = 12.0
a = [.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
a = np.array(a)
new_a = a/FootToInch
```

I get:

```
[0.04166667 0.08333333 0.125      0.16666667]
```

I don't want the first element rounded to that value.  I wanted it rounded to the same value
as simply dividing, I.e, `.5/12 = 0.041666666666666664`

Is there a way to change the rounding in the array to get the same value as `.5/12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a configuration in numpy that sets the level of precision when values are **printed to the screen**.

To set that precision, you use the `.set_printoptions()` method.

To show what effect the printoption has on the visual outputs, I ran this through a range of print settings from 6 digits of precision up to by not including 20 digits in steps of 2 and calculated the value

```
FootToInch = 12.0
a = [.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
a = np.array(a)

for prec in range(6, 20, 2):
    np.set_printoptions(prec)
    print(prec, ':', a/FootToInch)
```

This results in the following outputs:

```
6 : [0.041667 0.083333 0.125 0.166667]
8 : [0.04166667 0.08333333 0.125 0.16666667]
10 : [0.0416666667 0.0833333333 0.125 0.1666666667]
12 : [0.041666666667 0.083333333333 0.125 0.166666666667]
14 : [0.04166666666667 0.08333333333333 0.125 0.16666666666667]
16 : [0.0416666666666667 0.0833333333333333 0.125 0.1666666666666667]
18 : [0.041666666666666664 0.08333333333333333 0.125 0.16666666666666666]
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It's really a display rounding issue, though there is an underlying dependence on the float precision:

```
In [189]: .5/12
Out[189]: 0.041666666666666664
In [190]: np.float64(.5)/np.float64(12)
Out[190]: 0.041666666666666664
In [191]: np.float32(.5)/np.float32(12)
Out[191]: 0.041666668
In [192]: np.float128(.5)/np.float128(12)
Out[192]: 0.041666666666666666668
```

With multiprecision math:

```
In [8]: mpmath.fraction(5,120)
Out[8]: <5/120: 0.0416667~>
```

Rounding to `7` the mathematically correct approach regardless of precision.

The default print options seek to balance detail with readability, especially for larger arrays:

```
In [194]: np.array([.5,1,1.5,2])/12
Out[194]: array([0.04166667, 0.08333333, 0.125     , 0.16666667])
In [195]: (np.array([.5,1,1.5,2])/12).tolist()
Out[195]: [0.041666666666666664, 0.08333333333333333, 0.125, 0.16666666666666666]
```